# Manipulating the string using powershell

Tags: powershell

Using a string **environment-type1-01-x** I am able to make the format, as expected

```
$string = 'environment-type1-01-x'
$a = $string.Split('-')[0]
$b = $string.Split("-")[1]
$c = $string.Split("-")[2]
$d = $string.Split("-")[3]
$e = "-("
$f = "))"
write-host "$a$e$b$e$c$f"
```

**Output:** environment-(type1-(01))

But, how can I do the same for multiple strings in a file as below:

```
environment-type1-01-x
environment-type2-01-x
environment-type3-01-x
environment-type3-02-x
environment-type3-11-x
```

Looking for the output as below using the above file...
**`environment-(type1-(01)|type2-(01)|type3-(01|02|11))`**

I tried for a string and able to get the format. But, for multiple strings, unable to get the desired output.

Comment: calling `$string.Split` multiple times is very inefficient. Better store in a variable `$s = $string.Split('-'); $a = $s[0], $b = $s[1]...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Group-Object` using a calculated expression to group by the the `typeX` where `X` is any amount of digits, then loop through each group and extract the digits between the hyphens to create a string like:

```
type1-(01)
type2-(01)
type3-(01|02|11)
```

Lastly you can join these strings with `|` and interpolate it between `environment-(` and the closing `)`:

```
$strings = @'
environment-type1-01-x
environment-type2-01-x
environment-type3-01-x
environment-type3-02-x
environment-type3-11-x
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# group by the digits coming right after 'type'
$groups = $strings | Group-Object { [regex]::Match($_, 'type\d+-').Value }
# loop thru each group
$result = foreach($group in $groups) {
    # get the digits between the hyphens
    $digits = foreach ($line in $group.Group) {
        [regex]::Match($line, '(?<=-)\d+(?=-)').Value
    }
    # create a string using the name of the group and the joined digits
    '{0}({1})' -f $group.Name, ($digits -join '|')
}
# create a string using the joined groups
'environment-({0})' -f ($result -join '|')
```

Comment: @Santiage Squarzon  :  Thanks for your input, but how we can achieve the same if the above content is in text file. Please help me on the same...

Comment: Here, type1, type2 will will different values like (abc, xyz, trs). Then the output is not coming as expected... Please help me for the below content...
environment-abc-01-x
environment-abc-02-x
environment-type-01-x
environment-xyz-01-x
environment-xyz-02-x
environment-xyz-11-x